# Unable to add attribute to product by InstallData

Tags: magento2, database, custom-attributes, installdata

I would like to add a custom attribute to the product and create an installData.php according to the guide. However, nothing changed after se:up. Please help.

app/code/My/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'sample_attribute',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'csutom_attribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
}

public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [];
}

public function getAliases()
{
    return [];
}

public static function getVersion()
{
    return '1.0.0';
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create an attribute after creating the module and then run s:u to upgrade the database?

If it is, you need to change the setup version first to UpgradeSchema to create an attribute or manually delete the entry of your custom module from the database table name: **setup_module**.

To change version:

Go to vendor/module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="<vendor>_<module>" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

And change the setup version here. Or change the version to your static method.

```
public static function getVersion()
{
    return '1.0.0';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't see the new attribute after s:u even changed the version as per your advice.

Comment: Did you try to delete the entry table name: setup_module and reinstall your module? @hill2011

Comment: I think just the delay and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: That's good to know @hill2011